# What different between "IndexIgnore *" and "IndexIgnore */*"

Tags: .htaccess

Im using IndexIgnore to deny file listing.

```
IndexIgnore *

IndexIgnore */*
```

Im tested all of them and nothing change but..

What different between of them :D

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IndexIgnore *
```

tells apache to Hide all files and dirs from the directory listing.

```
 IndexIgnore */*
```

The line above tells apache to hide a spacific file or dir from the listing.

Examples :

```
 * = All files a dirs.
 */* = Hides the root dir.
 *foo.php* = hides /foo.php
```

Wildcard expression :

```
* = matches Any chars
*foo = matches a string starting with any chars followed by "foo".
file.* = matches a string starting with "file." followed by any chars.
```

Comment: So the "IndexIgnore *" and "IndexIgnore */*"is same rule ?